Component is missing template or render function
This is a stupid question, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.
Trying to setup CK5 in Vue and I'm running into some issues. Getting this error: Component is missing template or render function.
We are on Vue3, Nuxt3, Composition api, and we use script setup. I followed this tutorial: https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/builder/ with some slight modifications.
I thought that just adding the import CKEditor was enough to use a component.
The part from the tutorial that I think I'm missing is this, but we don't have that.  I'm assuming my issue is a lack of familiarity with Nuxt3?:
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import './style.css';
import App from './App.vue';
import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue';

createApp(App).use(CKEditor).mount('#app');

Template:
<template>
    <CKEditor :editor="editor" v-model="editorData" :config="editorConfig"></CKEditor>
</template>

Script:
import {
    ClassicEditor,
    AccessibilityHelp,
    Alignment,
    AutoImage,
    AutoLink,
    Autosave,
    Base64UploadAdapter,
    BlockQuote,
    Bold,
    CloudServices,
    Code,
    CodeBlock,
    Essentials,
    FontBackgroundColor,
    FontColor,
    FontFamily,
    FontSize,
    GeneralHtmlSupport,
    Heading,
    HorizontalLine,
    HtmlEmbed,
    ImageBlock,
    ImageCaption,
    ImageInline,
    ImageInsert,
    ImageInsertViaUrl,
    ImageResize,
    ImageStyle,
    ImageTextAlternative,
    ImageToolbar,
    ImageUpload,
    Indent,
    IndentBlock,
    Italic,
    Link,
    LinkImage,
    List,
    ListProperties,
    MediaEmbed,
    Paragraph,
    RemoveFormat,
    SelectAll,
    ShowBlocks,
    SourceEditing,
    Strikethrough,
    Table,
    TableCaption,
    TableCellProperties,
    TableColumnResize,
    TableProperties,
    TableToolbar,
    Underline,
    Undo
  } from 'ckeditor5';

  import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue';

  import { Template } from 'ckeditor5-premium-features';

  import 'ckeditor5/ckeditor5.css';
  import 'ckeditor5-premium-features/ckeditor5-premium-features.css';

  const LICENSE_KEY = 'LicenceKey';

    const isLayoutReady = ref(false)
        const config = ref(null) // CKEditor needs the DOM tree before calculating the configuration.
        const editor = ClassicEditor


    onMounted(() => {
        console.log('mounted')
      config.value = {
            toolbar: {
                items: [
                    'undo',
                    'redo',
                    '|',
                    'sourceEditing',
                    'showBlocks',
                    'selectAll',
                    '|',
                    'heading',
                    '|',
                    'fontSize',
                    'fontFamily',
                    'fontColor',
                    'fontBackgroundColor',
                    '|',
                    'bold',
                    'italic',
                    'underline',
                    'strikethrough',
                    'code',
                    'removeFormat',
                    '|',
                    'horizontalLine',
                    'link',
                    'insertImage',
                    'mediaEmbed',
                    'insertTable',
                    'insertTemplate',
                    'blockQuote',
                    'codeBlock',
                    'htmlEmbed',
                    '|',
                    'alignment',
                    '|',
                    'bulletedList',
                    'numberedList',
                    'outdent',
                    'indent',
                    '|',
                    'accessibilityHelp'
                ],
                shouldNotGroupWhenFull: false
            },
            plugins: [
                AccessibilityHelp,
                Alignment,
                AutoImage,
                AutoLink,
                Autosave,
                Base64UploadAdapter,
                BlockQuote,
                Bold,
                CloudServices,
                Code,
                CodeBlock,
                Essentials,
                FontBackgroundColor,
                FontColor,
                FontFamily,
                FontSize,
                GeneralHtmlSupport,
                Heading,
                HorizontalLine,
                HtmlEmbed,
                ImageBlock,
                ImageCaption,
                ImageInline,
                ImageInsert,
                ImageInsertViaUrl,
                ImageResize,
                ImageStyle,
                ImageTextAlternative,
                ImageToolbar,
                ImageUpload,
                Indent,
                IndentBlock,
                Italic,
                Link,
                LinkImage,
                List,
                ListProperties,
                MediaEmbed,
                Paragraph,
                RemoveFormat,
                SelectAll,
                ShowBlocks,
                SourceEditing,
                Strikethrough,
                Table,
                TableCaption,
                TableCellProperties,
                TableColumnResize,
                TableProperties,
                TableToolbar,
                Template,
                Underline,
                Undo
            ],
            fontFamily: {
                supportAllValues: true
            },
            fontSize: {
                options: [10, 12, 14, 'default', 18, 20, 22],
                supportAllValues: true
            },
            heading: {
                options: [
                    {
                        model: 'paragraph',
                        title: 'Paragraph',
                        class: 'ck-heading_paragraph'
                    },
                    {
                        model: 'heading1',
                        view: 'h1',
                        title: 'Heading 1',
                        class: 'ck-heading_heading1'
                    },
                    {
                        model: 'heading2',
                        view: 'h2',
                        title: 'Heading 2',
                        class: 'ck-heading_heading2'
                    },
                    {
                        model: 'heading3',
                        view: 'h3',
                        title: 'Heading 3',
                        class: 'ck-heading_heading3'
                    },
                    {
                        model: 'heading4',
                        view: 'h4',
                        title: 'Heading 4',
                        class: 'ck-heading_heading4'
                    },
                    {
                        model: 'heading5',
                        view: 'h5',
                        title: 'Heading 5',
                        class: 'ck-heading_heading5'
                    },
                    {
                        model: 'heading6',
                        view: 'h6',
                        title: 'Heading 6',
                        class: 'ck-heading_heading6'
                    }
                ]
            },
            htmlSupport: {
                allow: [
                    {
                        name: /^.*$/,
                        styles: true,
                        attributes: true,
                        classes: true
                    }
                ]
            },
            image: {
                toolbar: [
                    'toggleImageCaption',
                    'imageTextAlternative',
                    '|',
                    'imageStyle:inline',
                    'imageStyle:wrapText',
                    'imageStyle:breakText',
                    '|',
                    'resizeImage'
                ]
            },
            initialData:
                '<h2>Congratulations on setting up CKEditor 5! </h2>\n<p>\n    You\'ve successfully created a CKEditor 5 project. This powerful text editor will enhance your application, enabling rich text editing\n    capabilities that are customizable and easy to use.\n</p>\n<h3>What\'s next?</h3>\n<ol>\n    <li>\n        <strong>Integrate into your app</strong>: time to bring the editing into your application. Take the code you created and add to your\n        application.\n    </li>\n    <li>\n        <strong>Explore features:</strong> Experiment with different plugins and toolbar options to discover what works best for your needs.\n    </li>\n    <li>\n        <strong>Customize your editor:</strong> Tailor the editor\'s configuration to match your application\'s style and requirements. Or even\n        write your plugin!\n    </li>\n</ol>\n<p>\n    Keep experimenting, and don\'t hesitate to push the boundaries of what you can achieve with CKEditor 5. Your feedback is invaluable to us\n    as we strive to improve and evolve. Happy editing!\n</p>\n<h3>Helpful resources</h3>\n<ul>\n    <li> <a href="https://orders.ckeditor.com/trial/premium-features">Trial sign up</a>,</li>\n    <li> <a href="https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/index.html">Documentation</a>,</li>\n    <li>⭐️ <a href="https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5">GitHub</a> (star us if you can!),</li>\n    <li> <a href="https://ckeditor.com">CKEditor Homepage</a>,</li>\n    <li>‍ <a href="https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/demo/">CKEditor 5 Demos</a>,</li>\n</ul>\n<h3>Need help?</h3>\n<p>\n    See this text, but the editor is not starting up? Check the browser\'s console for clues and guidance. It may be related to an incorrect\n    license key if you use premium features or another feature-related requirement. If you cannot make it work, file a GitHub issue, and we\n    will help as soon as possible!\n</p>\n',
            licenseKey: LICENSE_KEY,
            link: {
                addTargetToExternalLinks: true,
                defaultProtocol: 'https://',
                decorators: {
                    toggleDownloadable: {
                        mode: 'manual',
                        label: 'Downloadable',
                        attributes: {
                            download: 'file'
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            list: {
                properties: {
                    styles: true,
                    startIndex: true,
                    reversed: true
                }
            },
            placeholder: 'Type or paste your content here!',
            table: {
                contentToolbar: ['tableColumn', 'tableRow', 'mergeTableCells', 'tableProperties', 'tableCellProperties']
            },
            template: {
                definitions: [
                    {
                        title: 'Introduction',
                        description: 'Simple introduction to an article',
                        icon: '<svg width="45" height="45" viewBox="0 0 45 45" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">\n    <g id="icons/article-image-right">\n        <rect id="icon-bg" width="45" height="45" rx="2" fill="#A5E7EB"/>\n        <g id="page" filter="url(#filter0_d_1_507)">\n            <path d="M9 41H36V12L28 5H9V41Z" fill="white"/>\n            <path d="M35.25 12.3403V40.25H9.75V5.75H27.7182L35.25 12.3403Z" stroke="#333333" stroke-width="1.5"/>\n        </g>\n        <g id="image">\n            <path id="Rectangle 22" d="M21.5 23C21.5 22.1716 22.1716 21.5 23 21.5H31C31.8284 21.5 32.5 22.1716 32.5 23V29C32.5 29.8284 31.8284 30.5 31 30.5H23C22.1716 30.5 21.5 29.8284 21.5 29V23Z" fill="#B6E3FC" stroke="#333333"/>\n            <path id="Vector 1" d="M24.1184 27.8255C23.9404 27.7499 23.7347 27.7838 23.5904 27.9125L21.6673 29.6268C21.5124 29.7648 21.4589 29.9842 21.5328 30.178C21.6066 30.3719 21.7925 30.5 22 30.5H32C32.2761 30.5 32.5 30.2761 32.5 30V27.7143C32.5 27.5717 32.4391 27.4359 32.3327 27.3411L30.4096 25.6268C30.2125 25.451 29.9127 25.4589 29.7251 25.6448L26.5019 28.8372L24.1184 27.8255Z" fill="#44D500" stroke="#333333" stroke-linejoin="round"/>\n            <circle id="Ellipse 1" cx="26" cy="25" r="1.5" fill="#FFD12D" stroke="#333333"/>\n        </g>\n        <rect id="Rectangle 23" x="13" y="13" width="12" height="2" rx="1" fill="#B4B4B4"/>\n        <rect id="Rectangle 24" x="13" y="17" width="19" height="2" rx="1" fill="#B4B4B4"/>\n        <rect id="Rectangle 25" x="13" y="21" width="6" height="2" rx="1" fill="#B4B4B4"/>\n        <rect id="Rectangle 26" x="13" y="25" width="6" height="2" rx="1" fill="#B4B4B4"/>\n        <rect id="Rectangle 27" x="13" y="29" width="6" height="2" rx="1" fill="#B4B4B4"/>\n        <rect id="Rectangle 28" x="13" y="33" width="16" height="2" rx="1" fill="#B4B4B4"/>\n    </g>\n    <defs>\n        <filter id="filter0_d_1_507" x="9" y="5" width="28" height="37" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">\n            <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>\n            <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" result="hardAlpha"/>\n            <feOffset dx="1" dy="1"/>\n            <feComposite in2="hardAlpha" operator="out"/>\n            <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.29 0"/>\n            <feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow_1_507"/>\n            <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow_1_507" result="shape"/>\n        </filter>\n    </defs>\n</svg>\n',
                        data: "<h2>Introduction</h2><p>In today's fast-paced world, keeping up with the latest trends and insights is essential for both personal growth and professional development. This article aims to shed light on a topic that resonates with many, providing valuable information and actionable advice. Whether you're seeking to enhance your knowledge, improve your skills, or simply stay informed, our comprehensive analysis offers a deep dive into the subject matter, designed to empower and inspire our readers.</p>"
                    }
                ]
            }
        };

        configUpdateAlert(config.value);

        isLayoutReady.value = true;
    })


    function configUpdateAlert(config) {
        if (configUpdateAlert.configUpdateAlertShown) {
            return;
        }

        const isModifiedByUser = (currentValue, forbiddenValue) => {
            if (currentValue === forbiddenValue) {
                return false;
            }

            if (currentValue === undefined) {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        };

        const valuesToUpdate = [];

        configUpdateAlert.configUpdateAlertShown = true;

        if (!isModifiedByUser(config.licenseKey, '<YOUR_LICENSE_KEY>')) {
            valuesToUpdate.push('LICENSE_KEY');
        }

        if (valuesToUpdate.length) {
            window.alert(
                [
                    'Please update the following values in your editor config',
                    'in order to receive full access to the Premium Features:',
                    '',
                    ...valuesToUpdate.map(value => ` - ${value}`)
                ].join('\n')
            );
        }
    }


In Nuxt 3 you install plugins slightly differently than Vue 3.
You need to:

create a CKEditor.js file in your /plugins directory (if you dont have one, create it)

in your CKEditor.js file add this:


import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue';

export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
   nuxtApp.use(CKEditor)
})

See here for more info:
https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/plugins
Can also remove this line:
createApp(App).use(CKEditor).mount('#app');
